# .push in javascript is self closing the div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In a item array, I am trying to push row(bootstrap class) and set a col-sm-6 classes (sub of row class, also from bootstrap class) with the help of a loop.

```
items.push('<div class="row display-flex">');

$.each(obj, function(i,val){           
        items.push('<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 display-flex"> \
                        <div class="thumbnail"> \
                            <div class="caption"> \
                                <h3 class="h3-margin-top-change">'+val.rm_name+'</h3> \
                            </div> \
                        </div> \
                        </div> \
                    </div> ');
}); 

items.push('</div>');
```

but the div is self closing

```
<div class="row display-flex"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 display-flex">
...
</div>
```

which cause the col tags to be unorganized. The expected answer is

```
<div class="row display-flex">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 display-flex">
     ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are all those `\\`` characters doing in your string? Where is `items` declared?

Comment: items is an array, it's pushing a string into the array. how can that possibly be adding an ending tag?

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` there after the one that closes the div with class `caption`

Comment: @ScottMarcus A backslash character ("\") at the end of a line indicates that the string will continue on the next line. [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: @some Why not just use template literal strings for that?

Comment: @ScottMarcus The template literal is a new thing. The backslash at the end of the string has been part of the standard since at least [ECMAScript 1](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf), that was released 1997, a little bit more than 20 years ago, and should be supported in every browser that runs javascript.

Comment: @some Thanks. Been using JS for 20+ years and never came across that!

Comment: @ScottMarcus It is the same principle that is used in other languages. For example bash.

Comment: @some I'm familiar with line continuation characters (old-school VB guy who used ` _`), just didn't know JS had it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers do self enclosing for most elements, if they are not enclosed.
Before appending the items array, join the elements.

```
$(element).html(items.join(''))
```

Comment: But, they don't do this when pushing strings into an array. Even if the strings contain HTML.